# How to check if current cell is in first row of table?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to check if the current cell in the table is on the first row. It must check inside the it's own table, not just the sheet. I couldn't find any info on this. Is this possible using a formula?  I want to do a special operation if this is the case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using native worksheet functions to construct a simple formula, you can retrieve the relative row position within the ListObject (aka *structured*) table by subtracting the header row.

```
=ROW()-ROW(Table1[#Headers])
```

The result could be compared to **1** to return a boolean result determining if you are in the first row of the table.

[image: listobject_relativerow]

Answer (score 2):

Consider:

```
Sub WhereIsTheActiveCell()
    Dim EquivRange As Range, r As Range
    Dim lo As ListObject
    Dim nFirstRow As Long, nLastRow As Long

    Set lo = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)

    With lo
        Set EquivRange = .DataBodyRange
        nFirstRow = EquivRange.Row
        nLastRow = EquivRange.Rows.Count + EquivRange.Row - 1
        If ActiveCell.Row = nFirstRow Then
            MsgBox "activecell is in the first data row of the table"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Row = nFirstRow - 1 Then
            MsgBox "activecell is the the header row of the table"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: There actually is an explicit [.HeaderRowRange property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.listobject.headerrowrange.aspx) in addition to the [.DataBodyRange property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.listobject.databodyrange.aspx) for ListObject tables.

Comment: @Jeeped  Thank you and thanks again for your help with my question yesterday.

Comment: No worries. The javascript conversion looks to be simpler (and just as random) but I had fun playing with it.

Comment: Thanks for this but I stick with the simple formula answer as I do not want to write a VBA script :)